# Collection_Select won't save to database even though parameters in console are correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm stuck trying to get my form with a collection_select to save. I have 3 models (Events, Users, Items), plus a joining model to link Items to Events (Event_Items).

My goal is for each users to be able to join events, and each user can specify a list of items they will bring to the event from an inventory that is unique to each user.

My form partial with collection select looks like this:

```
<%= form_for [@event, @event_items], remote: true do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>

<div class="form-group">

  <%= f.collection_select(:item_id, current_user.items.all, :id, :title, { :prompt => "Select an Item", :selected => @item_id}, { class: "form-control"}) %>
</div>

<%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary", id: "event-item-button" %>
```

My event_items_controller looks like:

```
 class EventItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def new
    @event_item = EventItem.new
  end


  def create
      @event_item = EventItem.new
      @event = Event.find(params[:id])

      if @event_item.save
        flash[:success] = "Item Added to List"   
        redirect_to @event
      else
        flash.now[:danger] = "Please try again"
        redirect_to @event
      end

  end

  def destroy
    @event_item = EventItem.find(params[:id])

  end

  private

    def event_item_params
      params.require(:event_item).permit(:event_id, :user_id, :item_id)
    end


end
```

In the Event show page, I have this section where I iterate over each attendee and render the Event_Item partials:

```
            <% @event.attendees.each do |user| %>
             <div class="col-md-4">
                 #should render each existing item on the list. 
                 #Doesn't work yet
                 <%= render 'event_items/event_item' %>
             </div>     

             <% if user == current_user %>
                #renders dropdown with only current user's inventory
                #currently shows items correctly, just doesn't save to 
                #database
                <%= render 'event_items/form' %>
             <% end %>

            <% end %>
```

Whenever I hit the Submit button after selecting an Item in the dropdown, nothing is saved to the database, although the server console shows:

```
Started POST "/Events/27/event_items" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-09-26 19:54:32 -0500
Processing by EventItemsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "event_item"=>{"user_id"=>"5", "item_id"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Submit", "event_id"=>"27"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)



ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Event without an ID):

app/controllers/event_items_controller.rb:11:in `create'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `create` action, you do:

```
@event = Event.find(params[:id])
```

But, `params` doesn't have `:id`, it has `:event_id`. So, it should probably be:

```
@event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
```

And, your `create` action should probably look more like:

```
def create

  @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
  @event_item = @event.event_items.new(event_item_params)

  if @event_item.save
    flash[:success] = "Item Added to List"   
    redirect_to @event
  else
    flash.now[:danger] = "Please try again"
    redirect_to @event
  end

end
```

By doing:

```
@event_item = @event.event_items.new(event_item_params)
```

`event_id` will be set on the new `event_item`. (This assumes, naturally, that `Event has_many :event_items` and `EventItem belongs_to :event`.)

Comment: Thanks for your help. That seems to get me a little closer, but in my server console it's now showing 

ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'item_id' for EventItem.):

app/controllers/event_items_controller.rb:12:in `create'. 

Line 12 would be the @event_item = @event.event_items.new(event_item_params). It doesn't seem to make sense since it is still showing the parameters with an item_id with an existing item.

Comment: Welp, does `EventItem` have the attribute `item_id`? You don't show anything about your `EventItem` model, so it's hard to tell what you have in there.

Comment: EventItem model has:
belongs_to :event
belongs_to :item

Comment: But does your table actually have `item_id`? Also, it seems like `EventItem` should `belong_to :user` and have a `user_id` attribute (column in the table).

Comment: My bad, the table actually had "items_id" instead of "item_id". That's where the mix up was. I changed the schema and database and it's saving correctly now. Thank you for your help.